# How to map classes in NHibernate using Roles or Composition

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I believe this is a common question / problem but have not been able to find a good clean concise answer.

**The Problem**

How to map entities that appear to have an inheritance relationship:

```
Company
  Supplier
  Manufacturer
  Customer
```

However, a Supplier can be a Manufacturer.

or

```
Person
  Doctor
  Patient
  Employee
```

Where a Patient can be a Doctor or can be an Employee.

**Suggestion:  Use Roles**

In discussions on the NHibernate forums, the response is often that this is multiple inheritance.

http://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=959076

They solution suggested is to use composition or to use "Roles".  However, I cannot find any examples or explanation on how exactly to do that.

> "Favor composition over inheritance."
>   Remember that little goodie from
>   class? In this instance I have to
>   agree that you are trying multiple
>   inheritance-- not possible in C# or
>   Java (yet). I, personally, would
>   encourage you to think about
>   re-modeling so you have a Person
>   object and a person has a one-to-many
>   collection of Roles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to consider using the Roles. So a Role will have a set of Persons. Or a Person will have a set of Roles or both. This would probably imply that there is an Association class that maps persons to roles.

Define a Person class with all properties that are common to people. Then define a Role super class and DoctorRole, PatientRole and EmployeeRole sub classes (Assuming that each role has different properties).

The Person class can have a Collection of roles defined and the Role class can have a Collection of people defined. Or it might be easier to create an Association class, lets call it PeopleRole.

[This](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/example-mappings.html) page explains how to do the mapping so that PeopleRole is a composite element. Look at the Order/Product/LineItem example. Your Person is like Order, PeopleRole is like LineItem and Role is like Product.

Comment: The piece that I failed to grasp was the DoctorRole, PatientRole, etc subclasses!  The link is helpful too!  Thanks

Comment: @TedOnTheNet Thanks for the heads up. I will have to look for the new location of that page.

Comment: Unfortunately the link is dead :( That is why it is always better to put the solution directly here.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that this is more a question around how to model a domain well, rather than an NHibernate mapping issue.

Once you've sorted out your domain modelling, I think you'll find the NHibernate mapping falls out relatively easily.

One place to look to get your head around the idea of modeling Roles is to look for "[Color Modeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_colors)" - [Jeff de Luca](http://www.nebulon.com/) has [some resources](http://www.nebulon.com/articles/fdd/adsposters.html), though the idea originated with [Peter Coad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Coad)

The basic idea is to separate the identity of a participant from the role they play in an activity.

For example, you might have a Person object that captures the identify of a particular person.

Then, a completely separate object "Student" that captures the additional information to record the enrolment of a person as a student. Each instance of Student would have a reference to the person enrolled. A single person may be related to many "Student" records, one for each distinct enrolment.

In parallel, you could have a distinct "Tutor" object that records employment details when someone is hired to teach students in one-on-one situations. The Tutor object captures the additional details around how someone is employed as a tutor.

This structure gives you great flexibility - one person (Joe Bloggs) may just be a student, another person (Jane Doe) may just be a tutor, and a third (Chuck Norris) may be both.

Also, introducing another role (Lecturer, Marker, Administrator) becomes easier because the additions don't require changes to existing objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was helpful in understanding from a modeling perspective.  You're right, it is more of a domain modeling question than NHibernate specific.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a bit more commentary you might find relevant:

In a [blog post on the Naked Objects blog](http://blog.nakedobjects.net/?p=60) a few different approaches are outlined discussing the pros and cons of each.

- Using an 'Any' association mapping
- Modelling roles as classes

Comment: That article looks promising.  I didn't have time to read it in depth, but looks to be a good find.